# hyphens are an issue in getting contact details with a partial phone number

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider

I have a function to get all contacts with part of a phone number, here...

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
              new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER},
              Phone.NUMBER + " like ?",
              new String[] {"%"+String.valueOf(phoneNumber) +"%"}, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String id = c.getString(0);
    String number = c.getString(1);
    Log.d("id",id);
    Log.d("number",number);
}
```

but the problem is - IF i insert  `31221` I can't get contacts with a phone number like `312-2131-321`
Because of `"-"` or i if i insert `0558836298` i cant get `+62558836298` because of `"+"` and country code.
Thanks for the help

PS I do know about

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
```

but that works only if you put the whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to replace this:

```
Phone.NUMBER
```

with this:

```
"replace("+Phone.NUMBER+", '-','')"
```

It's using replace function from SQLite to remove hypens.

Comment: Change selection field or selection args?

Comment: what about country code, for example if i insert 05588... when country code is for example +662 and in database is storage +662558845678

Comment: I've edited code - you need to change selection fields (actually field) into SQLite function. As far as I remember - you cal also use some kind of regexps to remove all non digit chars.